# Flutter: how to get the name of place from google map

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I created a google map in flutter which is working perfectly, i want to get the name of place, please help me to get this, is there way to do this using latitude and longitude?
here is my code

```
class _locationState extends State<location> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap=Completer();
  late GoogleMapController newGoogleMapController;
  double mapbottompadding=0;

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldkey=new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
   late Position currentpositon;
  var geolocator=Geolocator();

  void locatepostion() async{
    Position position=await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    currentpositon=position;

    LatLng latLngPosition=LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition=new CameraPosition(target: latLngPosition,zoom: 14);
    newGoogleMapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
  }

  static final CameraPosition googlepostion=CameraPosition(target: LatLng(37.4249,-122.0657));
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        Container(
        child:GoogleMap(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: mapbottompadding),
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          zoomControlsEnabled: true,
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
           initialCameraPosition: googlepostion,
           onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
              _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
              newGoogleMapController=controller;
              setState(() {
                mapbottompadding=300.0;
              });
              
              locatepostion();
          },
        )
      )],),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do this through the Google Maps plugin on Flutter, but you can use [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#ReverseGeocoding) to obtain an address and other relevant info from longitude/latitude. Maybe check [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview) to get info on business entities.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [geocoding: ^2.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding) package to get location name from longitude & latitude  or  get longitude & latitude

// for longitude and latitude from location name

```
List<Location> locations = await locationFromAddress("Gronausestraat 710, Enschede");
```

// for location name from longitude and latitude

```
List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(52.2165157, 6.9437819);
```

Answer (score 1):

use geocoding package to get current latitude and longitude. then pass latitude and longitude to this {placemarkFromCoordinates} function.

it will provide use the list of Placemark object which has many information.
such as name , sub locality ,area , postal code etc.

```
List<Placemark> placemarks =
          await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);

Placemark place1 = placemarks[0];
Placemark place2 = placemarks[1];
String _currentAddress =
            "${place1.name} ${place2.name} ${place1.subLocality} 
${place1.subAdministrativeArea} ${place1.postalCode}";
```